# How do I combine customized map markers with Google Map's autocomplete search box?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have managed to create code that displays customized, clickable markers on Google Maps. I also have a separate interface that searches locations from Google Maps' database using Autocomplete. I'm having trouble combining these two.

Here is the code for the one with the search box (w/o my API Key):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hoshizora Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #description {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
      #infowindow-content .title {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      #infowindow-content {
        display: none;
      }
      #map #infowindow-content {
        display: inline;
      }
      .pac-card {
        margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
      }
      #pac-container {
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        margin-right: 12px;
      }
      .pac-controls {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 11px;
      }
      .pac-controls label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }
      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }
      #title {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 6px 12px;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Schools of Current Adik Bintang in DIY</h2>
    <!--Card Information Division-->
    <div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
      <div>
        <div id="title">
          Lokasi Adik Bintang
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="pac-container">
        <input id="pac-input" type="text"
            placeholder="Enter an Adik Bintang">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <!--Popup Information Card Division-->
    <div id="infowindow-content">
      <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
      <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
      <span id="place-address"></span>
    </div>

  <script>
      //Map Interface
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat:-7.88806,lng:110.32889},
          zoom: 12
        });

        //defines card to
        var card = document.getElementById('pac-card');
        //corners the box (card)
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);

        //defines input for AutoComplete
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        //software for Autocomplete
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        //Zooms into the area searched
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
        //completes the search and defines/pulls out info window
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        //info window content
        var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
        infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
        function addMarker(props){}
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          //puts the window properly
          map: map,
          //how far the window is with the marker
          anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
        });


        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          //idk with these two do
          infowindow.close();
          marker.setVisible(true);
          //Makes it Happen
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.geometry) {
            // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
            window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
            return;
          }

          // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);
          }
          marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
          //idk
          marker.setVisible(true);

        //shows the infobox
          var address = '';
          if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
              //infobox formula
              (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
          }

          //Content
          infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
          infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
          infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
          //shows the window
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        document.getElementById('use-strict-bounds')
            .addEventListener('click', function() {
              console.log('Checkbox clicked! New state=' + this.checked);
              autocomplete.setOptions({strictBounds: this.checked});
            });
      }
    </script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[APIKEY]&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for the map with one customized marker(w/o my API Key):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hoshizora Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
     * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
      height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #description {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
      #infowindow-content .title {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      #infowindow-content {
        display: none;
      }
      #map #infowindow-content {
        display: inline;
      }
      .pac-card {
        margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
      }
      #pac-container {
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        margin-right: 12px;
      }
      .pac-controls {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 11px;
      }
      .pac-controls label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }
      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }
      #title {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 6px 12px;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Schools of Current Adik Bintang in DIY</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        //New map options
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat:-7.88806,lng:110.32889},
          zoom: 12
        });

      //HEC
      addMarker({
        coords:{lat:-7.892623,lng:110.301695},
        iconImage:'HEC.jpg',
        content:'<h3>Hoshizora Educational Center<br>Headquarters</h3><img src = "HEC-BUILDING.jpg"<br><h3><a href="https://www.hoshizora.org/contact/">Contact Us</a></h3>'
      });

      // Add Marker Function
      function addMarker(props){
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:props.coords,
        map:map,
        icon:props.iconImage
      });
      // Check for custom icon
      if(props.iconImage){
        // Set icon image
        marker.setIcon(props.iconImage);
      }
      // Check content
      if(props.content){
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content:props.content
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function(){
          infoWindow.open(map,marker);
        marker.addListener('click', function(){
          infoWindow.close(map,marker);
        marker.addListener('click', function(){
          infoWindow.open(map,marker);
        marker.addListener('click', function(){
          infoWindow.close(map,marker);
        marker.addListener('click', function(){
          infoWindow.open(map,marker);
          })
          })
        })
        })
        });
      }
    }
  }

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[APIKEY]&libaries=places&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to somehow combine these two codes to one interface in which I can search locations with the created customized markers visible on the map. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this one is pretty simple.

I modified your code #1. I used a sample icon that I manage to get from Google images (please don't use this to avoid copyright issues).

I've added an '**icon**'  property in your Marker object (here's the documentation for **[Icon object specification](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Icon))**. Under the **icon's** **url** property, I referenced the path of the icon that I will be using and supplied values to **scaledSize** property for scaling (use this property to stretch/shrink an image or a sprite).

Then in your infowindow, I've created an HTML template in **template** variable. In there, I've placed the thumbnail, address, and the link to your website. I've also added css for that template in the head section.

Here's the live **[demo](https://jsbin.com/dequka/edit?html,output)**

The marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  icon : {
      url : 'https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/65999-200.png',
      scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(60,60),
  },
  map: map,
  anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -50)
});
```

the infowindow content:

```
var template = '<div class="customInfoWindowContentHolder">'
    template += '<div class="title">'+place.formatted_address+'</div>';
    template += '<div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/65999-200.png"></img></div>';
    template += '<div class="linkBottom"><a href="https://www.hoshizora.org/contact/" >Contact Us</a></div>';
    template += '</div>';
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for the reply. This is for a big project to be used for the ICT of an educational NGO in Indonesia :) But one thing, is there a way for the clickable marker (the one presented in code #2, location of Hoshizora) to be visible on the map?

Comment: If this helped, please consider upvoting/accepting my answer :).

Comment: Yeah, will do. I'm just trying to find a way to have visible markers show up as well, so currently attempting to figure that out right now.

Comment: It's beautiful! I will review the code and see what I had missing...and then incorporate the code into the work team's personal code. Big thanks from Indonesia! Too bad I don't have enough reputation for the upvote.